# Javascript regex replace text with emoticons

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I need to replace text like `;)` or `:p` by emoticon but I can't create a regex in order to detect this. Now i can detect only like `:wink:`

```
function replaceEmoticons(text) {
  var emots = {
    ";)": "wink",
    ":)": "xxx",
    ":p": "xxx", 

  };

  return text.replace(/:(.*?):/g, function (match) {
    return typeof emots[match] != 'undefined' ?
           '<img src="http://localhost:8080/'+emots[match]+'.png"/>' :
           match;
  });
}
```

What is the good regex for that ?

Comment: Why do you need a regex in the firstPlace? Just do `yourString.replaceAll(":wink:", winkSource)`

Comment: sorry i edit my post i need to replace all array example `;)` by wink.png or `:)` by smile.png

Comment: @Bálint I'm pretty sure there is no "replaceAll" on String's prototype...

Comment: @Miky, can you add an exemplary input string(text)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following.However, you should escape the special characters ( and ) in your smileys when making the regexes.

//helper function to escape special characters in regex

```
function RegExpEscape(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"); 
}

function replaceEmoticons(text) {   
    var emoticons = {
        ':)'         : 'smile.gif',
        ':('         : 'sad.gif',
        ';)'         : 'wink.gif'


    }

    var result = text;
    var emotcode;
    var regex;

    for (emotcode in emoticons)
    {
        regex = new RegExp(RegExpEscape(emotcode), 'gi');
        result = result.replace(regex, function(match) {
            var pic = emots[match.toLowerCase()];

            if (pic != undefined) {
                return '<img src="' + pic + '"/>';
                    } else {
                return match;
                    }
                });
    }

    return result;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function takes a string and returns a string with all the replacements found inside of the `emots` object.

```
function replaceText(text) {
  var emots = {
    ";)": "wink",
    ":)": "xxx",
    ":p": "xxx", 
  };

  for(var key in emots){
    if(emots.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      text = text.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(key), 'g'), '<img src="http://localhost:8080/' + emots[key] + '.png"/>');
    }
  }
  return text;
}

function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified [AK1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37954137/1762224) and provided an example.

```js
// Official Twitch robot emotes: https://twitchemotes.com
var emoticons = {
  ':)'   : 'ebf60cd72f7aa600',
  ':('   : 'd570c4b3b8d8fc4d',
  ':o'   : 'ae4e17f5b9624e2f',
  ':z'   : 'b9cbb6884788aa62',
  'B)'   : '2cde79cfe74c6169',
  ':\\'  : '374120835234cb29',
  ';)'   : '3407bf911ad2fd4a',
  ';p'   : '3407bf911ad2fd4a',
  ':p'   : 'e838e5e34d9f240c',
  'R)'   : '0536d670860bf733',
  'o_O'  : '8e128fa8dc1de29c',
  ':D'   : '9f2ac5d4b53913d7',
  '>('   : 'd31223e81104544a',
  '<3'   : '577ade91d46d7edc'
}
// Convert the emoticon map entries into their fully-qualified paths.
mapIdsToPaths(emoticons,
              'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/',
              'chansub-global-emoticon-',
              '24x18');

// Replace all possible emotes in each paragraph.
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(e => e.innerHTML = replaceEmoticons(e.innerHTML, emoticons));

function replaceEmoticons(text, emotes) {
   return Object.keys(emotes).reduce((result, emote) => {
      return result.replace(new RegExp(RegExpEscape(emote), 'gi'), function(match) {
        return (img => img != null ? '<img src="' + img + '"/>' : match)(emotes[match]);
      });
    }, text);
}

// helper function to escape special characters in regex
function RegExpEscape(text) {
  return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}

// Map emote ids to their URLs.
function mapIdsToPaths(emotes, url, prefix, size) {
  Object.keys(emotes).forEach((id) => {
    emotes[id] = url + prefix + emotes[id] + '-' + size + '.png';
  });
}
```

```html
<p>Hello ;)<p>
<p>How are you :)?<p>
<p>o_O Today was not a good day... :(<p>
```